# Shutdown .Netcore IHostedService as Console App

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have built Generic Host (IHostedService) in .netcore 2.2. I am running HostBuilder as RunConsoleAsync().
RunConsoleAync() will wait for Ctrl + C to close application.
I want to close console app as soon as StartAsync() process complete instead of user has to press ctrl + c.

I tried to Invoke StopAsync() with new CancellationToken(true), but it is not helping me.

I developed this as IHostedService, because this app will be deployed on multiple plateform.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I assume you have the `IHostedService` implementation in place. All you need to do is inject `IHostApplicationLifetime` and use that to stop the application as shown below:

```
    public class Service : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _applicationLifetime;
    public Service(IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime)
    {
        _applicationLifetime = applicationLifetime;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        ...

        _applicationLifetime.StopApplication();
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed the ability to shut down a service running on my web host.
They don't provide the granular ability to choose a specific web service that is running & I was having to continually shut down my entire site.  I wanted to be able to call a WebAPI method in my service & shut it down just the one service instead of having to stop IIS & restart.

Here's how you can add the ability to shutdown your service from your `HomeController` (or any other controller in your project).

In your `HomeController` add the following code:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
      private IHostApplicationLifetime _lifeTime; // add private member
      // add appLifetime parameter to constructor 
      public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _lifeTime = appLifetime;  // init the private member var
    }
```

Now, we can add a method that you can access via JavaScript [fetch()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) for example.

Further down in the `HomeController` add the following method.

```
[HttpGet("StopService")]
    public ActionResult StopService(){
        _lifeTime.StopApplication();
        return new JsonResult(new {result="true",message="<YourServiceName> is shutting down."});
    }
```

Now you can make a call to your service (even from the browser console window) like the following:

```
fetch("http://localhost:5243/StopService")
   .then(result => result.json())
   .then(data => console.log(data));
```

When that call completes you will see something like the following in your console.

[image: json results]