# How to get and inject the IHostApplicationLifetime in my service to the container (Console App)

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection, console-application, ioc-container

Following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55960329/375460), I want to inject the `IHostApplicationLifetime` in my class to shutdown properly when the method `StartAsync` is over.

But I don't know how to get the applicationLifetime from the console and Inject it through de built-in dotnet core IoC container:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
{
    return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            config.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
        })
        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.Configure<ConnectionStringConfiguration>(hostContext.Configuration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings"));
            services.AddTransient<ISmtpClient, MySmtpClient>();
            services.AddTransient<IEmailService, EmailService>();
            services.AddSingleton<IHostApplicationLifetime>(????); // What should I put here ????
            services.AddHostedService<EInvoiceSenderService>();
        })
        .UseSerilog();
}
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is already added by default by the framework, so you should be able to access it from the hosted service as an injected dependency.

Simplified example

```
public class EInvoiceSenderService: IHostedService {
    private readonly ILogger logger;
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime;

    public EInvoiceSenderService(
        ILogger<LifetimeEventsHostedService> logger, 
        IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime) { //<--- INJECTED DEPENDENCY
        this.logger = logger;
        this.appLifetime = appLifetime;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        appLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnStarted);
        appLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnStopping);
        appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(OnStopped);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }


    private void OnStarted() {
        logger.LogInformation("OnStarted has been called.");

        // Perform post-startup activities here
    }

    private void OnStopping() {
        logger.LogInformation("OnStopping has been called.");

        // Perform on-stopping activities here
    }

    private void OnStopped() {
        logger.LogInformation("OnStopped has been called.");

        // Perform post-stopped activities here
    }    
}
```

Reference: [.NET Generic Host: IHostApplicationLifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/generic-host?view=aspnetcore-3.0#ihostapplicationlifetime-1)

Comment: Thank you !! Without your answer, I'll be searching again & again...

Comment: Even though the documentation says the same, it seems like you cannot register a method that returns "void". It has to return an Acion. Maybe something changed and the documentation wasn't updated? Idk.

Comment: I don't understand this answer, the code bears no resemblance to the code in the question.

Comment: @PaulMcCarthy the code in the question is showing how they registered the `EInvoiceSenderService` service. The code in the answer shows an example of how the service is implemented. The OP was asking how to register `IHostApplicationLifetime` so that it can be injected into the service. The answer explains that `IHostApplicationLifetime` is automatically registered and that all they have to do is make sure it is in the constructor of the service.

Comment: @Nkosi This is all part of the .NET dependency injection system.  What adds to my confusion, I'm trying to write a Windows service but most of the docs are around ASP.NET hosted services.  OK, I'm now seeing they all share a lot of common stuff, but no one explicitly states this anywhere I can find.  For this particular item, there's a list of stuff that can be "auto-injected" into your constructor as part of .NET Core:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0#framework-provided-services

Answer (score 8):

Previously (.net core 3.1), with use of startup class you can just throw additional parameters in the `Configure` method in a custom startup class.

```cs
...

WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
...

public class Startup
{
    public void Configure(
        IApplicationBuilder app,
        IWebHostEnvironment env,
        ILoggerFactory loggerFactory,
        IHostApplicationLifetime applicationLifetime,
        IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {

        ...

        // Register method to be called when the application shuts down.
        applicationLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnShutdown);
```

With .net 6, the `IHostApplicationLifetime` is available from a property on the main app:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddSingleton<IService, Service>();

var app = builder.Build();

IService service = app.Services.GetRequiredService<IService>();
ILogger logger = app.Logger;

// IHostApplicationLifetime is no longer obtained via dependency injection
IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime = app.Lifetime;  

IWebHostEnvironment env = app.Environment;

lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() =>
    logger.LogInformation(
        $"The application {env.ApplicationName} started" +
        $" with injected {service}"));
```

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/50-to-60-samples?view=aspnetcore-7.0