# unable to resolve service for type microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I am getting below error
unable to resolve service for type microsoft.extensions.hosting.ihostapplicationlifetime while attempting to activate a cless

below is the code in program.cs
services.AddSingleton<IOperationList,OperationList>()'''

in OperationList class i have a construction where i inject dependency
ihostapplicationlifetime interface

```
public OperationList(IIDBLocal idbLocal,IHostApplicationLifetime lifetime )
{
    lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(()=>
     {
            this.terminating =true;

     });
 }
```

Comment: Can this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59650230/how-to-get-and-inject-the-ihostapplicationlifetime-in-my-service-to-the-containe) help you solve this issue?