.NET Core 6 web application shutdown hook
Using Serilog in a C# .NET 6 web application, in the top-level startup code I have this:
var logger = app.Services.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
logger.LogInformation("The application has been initiated and is about to run");
app.Run();
logger.LogInformation("The application has been terminated");

I also have logging within the application. All of it works except the one appearing here after the app.Run() call. Apparently when the application is terminated, nothing after that is executed. Is there a hook I can implement that taps into the application's shutdown so I can log the termination event? If it makes a difference, I'm running this from within Visual Studio in the mode where it opens automatically in a browser and it terminates when the browser tab is closed.
@AdamVincent: Re your comment, that certainly looks like the approach I was looking for. But I tried
var logger = app.Services.GetService<ILogger<Program>>();
app.Lifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(() => logger.LogInformation("The application has been initiated and is about to run."));
app.Lifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(() => logger.LogInformation("The application is shutting down."));
app.Lifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(() => logger.LogInformation("The application has terminated."));

app.Run();

Result: The Started event got logged. The other two events didn't. Hmmm.

You're looking for IHostApplicationLifetime https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59650230/how-to-get-and-inject-the-ihostapplicationlifetime-in-my-service-to-the-containe

@AdamVincent: That certainly looked liked the approach I expected, but it didn't work! See my update in my original post.

I found this answered in another thread here, ASP.NET Core - Registering for Application Shutdown isn't working. Simply, it's that when the application is running in the debugger, it terminates abruptly on browser close or click of the Stop button. When I ran it using dotnet run instead, the Stopping and Stopped events were logged. Even then, on the other hand, the logging statement after the app.Run() call, still didn't run, so thanks to Adam Vincent for pointing me to the hooks.
